# Facebook instant article - Multiple url to same article

Tags: url-parameters, facebook-instant-articles

I have a rel=canonical link in facebook instant article as

```
www.domain.com?p=news&newsid=10
```

but when someone access to the link below with another ref parameter then it unable to read the facebook instant article and become to web page, because the link was different.

```
www.domain.com?p=news&newsid=10&ref=1
www.domain.com?p=news&newsid=10&ref=2
www.domain.com?p=news&newsid=10&ref=3
```

Any idea how can i develop one article with multiple link?

Answer (score 0):

From Instant Articles team here.

The key we have hold as Instant Article fetcher, is the canonical URL field.
For your cases, you should all of the links rendering same article and also all responses having as key canonical the following URL:

`www.domain.com?p=news&newsid=10`

This way you can render same Instant Article for any `ref=**` query param anyone shares within Facebook news feed.

You can also have on the `op-tracker` tags, these fields to better track your content, or even the original URL that was shared, for better tracking purposes check the example below, extracted from [this documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/analytics/):

```
<figure class="op-tracker">
    <iframe>
        <script>
            // The URL the user shared
            // (if there are no redirections, otherwise the final URL in the chain)
            var urlSharedByUser = ia_document.shareURL;

            // The article title
            var title = ia_document.title;

            // Referrer is always set to 'ia.facebook.com'
            var referrer = ia_document.referrer;
        </script>
    </iframe>
</figure>
```